# Displaying an Image in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, image, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm trying to display an image in a simple GUI using PySimpleGui but it might be a bit more complicated than I thought.

This is what I'm currently attempting:

```
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image
import sys

# GUI #


layout = [

        [sg.Image('2C.png')]
        [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]

         ]

window = sg.Window('My Program', layout)

button,values = window.read()
```

And this is the error Sublime is throwing out:

```
C:(Directory)file.py:12: SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple; perhaps you missed a comma?
  [sg.Image('2C.png')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 12, in <module>
    [sg.Image('2C.png')]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Really not sure what to google as there are so few PySimpleGUI resources out there.

Thanks for reading,

Callan

Comment: PySimpleGUI resources (no need for googling... just go there): Main Docs: http://www.PySimpleGUI.org  GitHub: http://www.PySimpleGUI.com  Open an Issue (questions, bugs, etc) http://Issues.PySimpleGUI.org  eCookbook: http://eCookbook.PySimpleGUI.org

Answer (score 4):

There is a missing comma after `[sg.Image('2C.png')]`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed comma. Please make sure the image is in Current Working Directory or supply full accessible path to image, Like this example.

```
image="/storage/emulated/0/Pycode2/folder.png"
```

or put pictures in this folders and change your Current directory by this code. This is not a good programming practice.

```
#choose directory to work use
os.chdir('/storage/emulated/0/Pycode2/')
```

Your correct code is this

```
layout = [

    [sg.Image('2C.png'),],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel(),],

     ]
```

Please note these Extra comma do NOT cause error and are very helpful to add new Layout items. A missing comma raises this error.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a GUI as per following code.
I have two different questions:

1. is it feasible to change the image by clicking on the one already existing, so that the new image can be saved with the updated form?
2. once the for is updated and saved, it is possible to upload only the filled fields (i.e the empty one are not displayed?

```py
# ----------- Importing Libraries ---------------

import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime
import base64


sg.theme('DarkTeal9')      
#------------------------------Create single layouts----------------------------------

flower_base64 = "image code is here"

layout_img = [[sg.Button('ciccio', image_data=flower_base64, button_color=(sg.theme_background_color(),sg.theme_background_color()),border_width=0, key='-GRAPH-')]]


   
layout_1 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT2-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1)),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST2-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN2-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN2-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9')]]


layout_a = [[sg.Button("row 2")]]

layout_2 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT3-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1)),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST3-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN3-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN3-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9')]]

layout_b =[[sg.Button("row 3")]]

layout_3 = [[sg.InputText("", key="-IT4-", font='Arial 9', size=(10,1), visible=True),
             sg.Combo(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"],size=(20,1), key='-TEST4-', font='Arial 9'),
             sg.CalendarButton("", close_when_date_chosen=True,  target='-IN4-', font='Arial 9', no_titlebar=False, format='%d-%b-%Y'),
             sg.InputText("", key='-IN4-', size=(20,1), font='Arial 9', justification="c")]]

#------------------------------Create master layout----------------------------------
               
layout = [[sg.Column(layout_img, key="-AZZ-")],
          [sg.Column(layout_1, key='-LAY1-'), sg.Column(layout_a, visible=True, key="-LAYA-")],
          [sg.Column(layout_2, visible=False, key='-LAY2-'), sg.Column(layout_b, visible=False, key='-LAYB-')],
          [sg.Column(layout_3, visible=False, key='-LAY3-')],
          [sg.Button ("Save"), sg.Button ("Load"), sg.Button("Upload"), sg.Button('Exit')]]
        

window = sg.Window("", layout, no_titlebar=True)


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
        
    if event == 'Save':
        filename = sg.popup_get_file("Save", save_as=True, no_window=True)
        window.SaveToDisk(filename)
    if event == 'Load':
        filename = sg.popup_get_file('Load', no_window=True)
        window.LoadFromDisk(filename)
        if "-IT2-":
            window[f'-LAY2-'].update(visible=True)
            window[f'-LAYA-'].update(visible=False)
        if "-IT3-":
            window[f'-LAY3-'].update(visible=True)
            
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
        window.close()
    if event == 'row 2':
        window[f'-LAY2-'].update(visible=True)
        window[f'-LAYA-'].update(visible=False)
        window[f'-LAYB-'].update(visible=True)
        layout = str(event)
    if event == 'row 3':
        window[f'-LAY3-'].update(visible=True)
        window[f'-LAYB-'].update(visible=False)
        layout = str(event)

window.close()
```

Comment: You can call method `update` to update the image for the Image element when click event if `enable_events=True`, or do something else.

Comment: Hi, I didn't catch your answer. Could you please explain better? I would just like to change  the image (for example browsing the picture files) w/o changing the code's string. Hoping to have clarified my idea...

Comment: Demo code in your another question.

Answer (score -1):

It might be able to work if you add the size of the image, like this:

```
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image
import sys


#Layout
layout = [

    [sg.Image('2C.png', size=(20, 20))]
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Exit')]

     ]

window = sg.Window('My Program', layout)
button,values = window.read()
if button == ('Exit', sg.WIN_CLOSED):
    break
```

Now try this

Comment: A comma missed in your layout list.